# Show $ M_1 \# M_2= U_1 \cup U_2 $ for some open subsets $U_i$ of manifolds $M_i$ such that the following properties hold.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, problem-solving

This is problem 4-19 of Lee's "Introdunction to topological manifolds" 2ed.

I want to show that for two connected $n$-manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$, there are open subsets $U_1$ and $U_2$ of the connected sum $M_1 \# M_2$ and points $p_i \in M_i$ such that $U_i \cong M_i\setminus \{p_i\}$, $U_1 \cap U_2 \cong \mathbb R^n \setminus\{0\}$, and $U_1 \cup U_2 = M_1 \# M_2$ where an equivalence means homeomophism.

What I have tried:

By definition, $M_1 \# M_2$ is formed by attaching $M_1 \setminus B_1$ to $M_2 \setminus B_2$ along the boundary. I tried choosing $p_i$'s to be the center of the coordinate balls $B_i$. Then if the equivalences were homotopy equivalences, the statement seems to be true.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let $V_i$ be the regular coordinate nbhd in $M_i$, contained in the larger coordinate nbhd $W_i$. The connected sum is the space $$(M_1\setminus V_1\sqcup M_2\setminus V_2)/(\partial V_1\sim\partial V_2)$$ Let $U_1$ be the image of $M_1\setminus V_1\sqcup W_2\setminus V_2$ in this quotient, and similarly for $U_2$.  The intersection of the $U_i$ is then the image of $$W_1\setminus V_1\sqcup W_2\setminus V_2$$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2622945/265452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up notation:

Let $B_i\subseteq M_i$ be open discs and $N_i$ normal neighbourhoods of the boundaries. Let $\varphi:N_1\to N_2$ a diffeomorphism that induces the gluing map (ie $\varphi$ maps the inward collar of $N_1$ to the outward collar of $N_2$ and vice versa). Let $V_i$ be the points of the open discs not in the normal neighbourhoods, note $V_i$ is a closed disk.

Then $M_1\#M_2$ is equal to $M_1 - V_1$ and $M_2-V_2$ glued along the normal collars, ie $M_1\#M_2$ is defined as the quotient space
$$(M_1- V_1) \cup_\varphi (M_2- V_2):= [(M_1-V_1)\cup (M_2-V_2)]/\{x\sim \varphi(x)\}$$

Let $U_i$ then be the image of $M_i- V_i$ in the quotient space. This is open since the quotient map necessarily is an open map. Further it is diffeomorphic to $M_i-V_i$ since this quotient map is a local diffeomorphism and it is injective on this set. The intersection $U_1\cap U_2$ is then the image of both normal neighbourhoods $N_1, N_2$ under the quotient mapping - infact these two neighbourhoods have the same image so it suffice to just take the image of $N_1$. But the quotient map is a local diffeomorphism and injective on $N_1$, hence $U_1\cap U_2\cong N_1$.

Now prove:

1. For any connected manifold $M$ if you remove a closed disk the result is diffeomorphic to $M-\{p\}$ for a point $p$.
2. A normal neighbourhood of the boundary of an $n$-dimensional ball is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n - \{0\}$.

Comment: Does everything hold if I change the word diffeomorphism to homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, but if you are looking at topological manifolds you need to be a bit more precise when talking about "normal" neighbourhoods.

Comment: Shouldn't the $V_i$'s be open disks for the quotient map to be defined?

Comment: You are removing the $V_i$ from the space - cutting out two closed discs, pushing two "collars" out and then gluing those two collars onto one-another.

Comment: And what is the definition of a normal nbd? Are they just the coordinate balls?

Comment: I am also confused if $U_1\cup U_2 = M_1 \# M_2$ holds for you choice of  $U_i$s.

Comment: I am actually in the context of topological manifolds...

Comment: $U_1\cup U_2 = M_1\# M_2$ follows directly from the definition. I suggest you draw a picture to make the construction more clear.